# Inconsistency between C++ std::string::compare() and the operator on string

Tags: c++, string, compare

Given the below piece of C++ code

```
cout<<("100">"035")<<"\n";
cout<<("100"<"035")<<"\n";
string str = "100";
cout<<str.compare("035");
```

The output of this code is

```
0
1
1
```

Which means "100" < "035" by the operator but "100" > "035" by the compare function. Is there any known implementation differences of these two?

P.S. "100" > "035" definitely makes more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C-String literals (such as `"100"`) compare themselves as pointer.

`std::string` comparison compare content lexicography.

If you want consistent results:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::cout << ("100"s > "035"s)<<"\n";
std::cout << ("100"s < "035"s)<<"\n";
std::string str = "100"s;
std::cout << str.compare("035");
```

`"100"s` is "equivalent" to `std::string("100")`.